# How to make a Alt+Tab and F5 hotkey in Autohotkeys

Tags: windows, autohotkey, alt-tab

I want to create a hotkey which does the following: Alt+Tab and F5 when I press Shift+CapsLock
in AutoHotkeys.

How can I do that?

Comment: Might want to edit your question. Because I am not sure how a bowel movement and key press can accomplish anything but embarrassment.

Answer (score 1):

```
+CapsLock::
SendInput !{Tab}
Sleep 100 ; Gives moment for computer to switch. Feel free to tweak this time.
SendInput {F5}
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

> CapsLock & +::AltTab & F5

should do it?
[autohotkey- Hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Remarks)

Comment: This does not work for me.